# Help con el siguiente codigo Datos Duplicados

Tags: java, poo, java-swing, aplicación-web

tengo que crear una agenda y tiene que validar el ingreso de datos para que no se repitan (lo quiero hacer por medio del nombre)
este es el codigo

```
void duplicar (){
             {            
        for (int i=0 ; i< jTable1.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            if (jTable1.getValueAt(i,1).equals(txtNombre.getText()))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El dato ya ha sido registrado");
                model.removeRow(i);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Tiene que ir en un boton Guardar que tiene el siguiente codigo

```
private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            try{
            String SQL = "INSERT INTO contactos(nombre,direccion,telefono,email)" + "VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ps.setString(1, txtNombre.getText());
            ps.setString(2, txtDirección.getText());
            ps.setString(3, txtTeléfono.getText());
            ps.setString(4, txtEmail.getText());
            
            int n = ps.executeUpdate();
            if(n > 0){
                Limpiar();
                mostrarDatos();
                LlenarTabla();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos guardados correctamente.");
                
            } if (n<0){
                LlenarTabla();
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

--como podria hacer?? para que me diga si esta duplicado y no lo guarde, caso contrario solo lo guarde

Comment: antes de guardar, chequea que no exista en la base de datos... o que tipo de chequeo estas buscando?

Comment: Lo que hago es que en el boton guardar agrego al inicio la funcion duplicar( ); para que la compile pero cuando corro el programa muestra el mensaje que "El dato ya ha sido registrado" pero despues aparece el mensaje de "Datos Guardados Correctamente". Porfa seria de mucha ayuda

Comment: si la funcion duplicar no devuelve nada, como sabe la otra funcion si esta duplicado o no?

Comment: Podrias ayudarme con algun modo para comunicarme contigo, ya sea cualquier red social. enserio necesito ayuda con el programa, asi podria mandarte capturas. La funcion duplicar lo que hace es buscar en la Tabla que tiene los datos otro valor que no se repita, y te manda un mensaje y "elimina" ese que vas a ingresar

Comment: Tu funcion duplicar manda un mensaje a la pantalla, pero no le dice a la funcion que la llamo, si hay un duplicado o no. Tu funcion duplicar devuelve void, cuando deberia devolver un boolean que diga si existe o no un duplicado, y en base a eso, la otra funcion seguir o terminar inmediatamente.... te recomendaria que leas el [tour] y tambien [ask]. me podes encontrar en el [chat] cuando llegues a 20 puntos de reputacion, o si no, en mi perfil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu funcion duplicar, no devuelve nada. Debe devolver algo, para que pueda ser usado.

```
boolean duplicar (){
{            
    for (int i=0 ; i< jTable1.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        if (jTable1.getValueAt(i,1).equals(txtNombre.getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El dato ya ha sido registrado");
            model.removeRow(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Y quien llama a la funcion, por ejemplo la funcion guardar, harias algo asi:

```
private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (duplicar())
    {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: De verdad, no sabes lo mucho que me has ayudado. Ya pude terminar el proyecto, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y cooperacion